# How do you get code-quality to only scan a specified directory?

Tags: environment-variables, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

From reading the documentation [here](http://vlabs.iitb.ac.in/gitlab/help/user/project/merge_requests/code_quality.md) I was able to get a working code-quality CI job added to my pipeline. The YAML looks like this

```
include:
  - template: Code-Quality.gitlab-ci.yml

code_quality:
  stage: test
  variables:
    SOURCE_CODE: "/src"
  artifacts:
    paths: [gl-code-quality-report.json]
```

However, even though I specify `SOURCE_CODE: /src` the job scans the entire project, not just the "src/" directory

How do I go about setting up .gitlab-ci.yml such that the Code-Quality CI job will only scan the "/src" directory? (The /src directory is located in the root of the project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a pattern to match all the files inside the `src` directory.

`SOURCE_CODE: src/**` will match all the files in the `src` directory tree.

Example Matches:

**src/foo/bar/xyz.java**

**src/abc.java**

Comment: I ended up having to use a .codeclimate.yml file to exclude everything except the src folder. Gitlab thinks it may be a regression. See https://forum.gitlab.com/t/code-quality-job-is-refusing-to-obey-source-code-env-variable/44077/8